# CreateProcess vs Command Line and missing DLL

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

When I use `CreateProcess` to start an application (InDesign) that is loading my plug-in, my plugin fails to load because a DLL my plugin uses can't be loaded. The strange thing is that if I double click the application or open it from a command line, my plugin loads fine.

My application that calls `CreateProcess` is quite large and itself uses several DLLs some of which are also used by my plug-in. I've narrowed it to the DLL that will will not load. I set it to delay load, the plugin now loads but will not load that DLL when I call it.

I've used "Process Explorer" to check out the application's PATH to make sure it's the same as when I open it from the command line. The path to the trouble DLL is in the PATH env, this is the same for other DLLs that load fine.

I launch many different apps with and without my plugins and have never seen something like this before.

Anybody know what might be going on?

**Oops...**

Well, I was wrong about the env PATH, it was different depending on how the application (InDesign) was launched. It looks like QuickTime changes the PATH for my application, placing it's "Apple Application Support" folder at the top. Inside that folder is a DLL with the same name as the one I'm using, namely libxml2.dll. When I load libxml2.dll in my plugin using LoadLibrary, msvcr80.dll can't be found. Shish.

Sorry for the distraction...

Comment: Have you tried using ShellExecuteW?

Comment: Yes, I've tried ShellExecuteEx, system, and CreateProcess all the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Check the working path when loading the application and/or plugin. Explorer and the command prompt normally set this explicitly but another application calling `CreateProcess()` may not.

Comment: I forgot to mention... I created a small application that uses CreateProcess and the trouble DLL. From this small application I can launch the application (InDesign) and my plugin loads fine.